# How many spacers were there?

Tags: isaac-asimov, robot-series

At the time of the Elijah Baley trilogy, what was the total population of the fifty spacer worlds together?

Solaria has 20,000 people according to *The Naked Sun*, but it's probably particularly sparsely populated even among spacer planets, and I have no idea how many the others have.  *The Naked Sun* also mentions that about 8,000,000,000 people live on Earth at this time.

Comment: Solaria is bizarrely sparse even by Spacer standards.  I'll see if I can find a reference for the population of the other spacer worlds.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From *The Caves of Steel*, Chapter 5, we have this quote from R. Daneel:

> One thing they never forget, you see, is that Earth’s population is
> eight billions, while the total population of the fifty Outer Worlds
> combined is scarcely more than five and a half billions.

Comment: Yikes, we have only a few months to populate the Outer Worlds with 5.5 billion people. Earth's population is projected to hit 8 billion in the next few months, before the end of 2022.

Comment: @shoover At least the wordsmiths have the copy ready for us: "A new life awaits you in the Off-world colonies. The chance to begin again in a golden land of opportunity and adventure!"